# Using flask MethodView

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to adapt this:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/

into the blueprint itself, (based on other blueprints I've looked at). Abstracting the api registration away from the application into the blueprint initialization. This is code from the flask documentation, with some changes.

This seems to work:

```
 class MyAPI(MethodView):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        bp = Blueprint(name, __name__)
        bp_endpoint = '{0}_api'.format(name)
        bp_url = '/{0}/'.format(name)
        bp_pk = '{0}_tag'.format(name)
        self.register_api(bp, bp_endpoint, bp_url, bp_pk, 'string')
        self._blueprint = bp

    def register_api(self, blueprint, endpoint, url, pk='id', pk_type='int'):
        view_func = self.as_view(endpoint)
        blueprint.add_url_rule(url, defaults={pk: None},
                         view_func=view_func, methods=['GET',])
        blueprint.add_url_rule(url, view_func=view_func, methods=['POST',])
        blueprint.add_url_rule('{0}<{1}:{2}>'.format(url, pk_type, pk), view_func=view_func,
                         methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])

    def get(self, my_tag):
         #... with post, put methods etc.
```

Then in my app I can just do this:

```
m = MyAPI('my')
app.register_blueprint(m._blueprint)
```

This seems to work, registers the urls so I can get:

```
Map([<Rule '/my/' (POST, OPTIONS) -> my.my_api>,
 <Rule '/my/<my_tag>' (PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS, GET) -> my.my_api>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>,
 <Rule '/my/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> my.my_api>])
```

However, I get an error when going to the route now (I've just tried GET):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1504, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1264, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1262, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1248, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/media/686e26f8-c6d4-4448-8fe4-c19802726dcb/projects/1_current/private/pycleaver/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 83, in view
    self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)
**TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**
```

aaand this is down a level or two lower than I'm able to think atm. Any input appreciated for what I've missed. I think it might have to do with the view_func in register_api initially.

edit:

sort of an answer

```
class MyAPI(MethodView):  

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        bp = Blueprint(name, __name__)
        self.endpoint = '{0}_api'.format(name)
        self.url = '/{0}/'.format(name)
        self.pk = '{0}_tag'.format(name)
        self._blueprint = bp
        self.register_api(self._blueprint, self.endpoint, self.url, self.pk)

    def register_api(self, bp, endpoint, url, pk ='id', pk_type='int'):
        view_func = self.__class__.as_view(endpoint)
        bp.add_url_rule(url, defaults={pk: None},
                     view_func=view_func, methods=['GET',])
        bp.add_url_rule(url, view_func=view_func, methods=['POST',])
        bp.add_url_rule('{0}<{1}:{2}>'.format(url, pk_type, pk), view_func=view_func,
                     methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you could keep your initialize method only one argument:

```
def __init__(self):
    bp = Blueprint("what?", __name__)  # here
    bp_endpoint = '{0}_api'.format(name)
    bp_url = '/{0}/'.format(name)
    bp_pk = '{0}_tag'.format(name)
    self.register_api(bp, bp_endpoint, bp_url, bp_pk, 'string')
    self._blueprint = bp
```

or give enough value in `as_view` without modifying your initialize method.

```
def register_api(self, blueprint, endpoint, url, pk='id', pk_type='int'):
    view_func = self.as_view(endpoint, name="what?")  # here
    # ... omit ...
```

But in my opinion, creating the blueprint inside the method view is not a good idea. A blueprint is a subapplication, which should be shared by many views.

Comment: I'm pulling from here: https://bitbucket.org/lost_theory/flask-stripe-blueprint/src but a different situation. If that way is incompatible with MethodView, then ok. I'm basically trying to instantiate apis in my application without tons of code. Hmm I do see your point though, and my attempt lacks finesse.

Comment: As it stands your sort of right about the blueprint, but the goal with this is to eventually abstract out the class to instantiate an api for any db object passed to it, in essence being an abstraction of a blueprint tailored and applied to each instance as part of initialization.

Comment: Then I thought `register_api` should be a static method or a class method, because the `as_view` is the factory method of the MethodView instance.